# Is punctured disc a Lipschitz domain?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, differential-geometry, euclidean-geometry

I don't quite understand how to apply the definition ([Understanding Lipschitz domain](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1125928/understanding-lipschitz-domain)) of Lipschitz domain. My question is about annulus (of which punctured disc is a special case). Is annulus a Lipschitz domain. How can we write its boundary(two disjoint circles) as the graph of a Lipschitz map locally? I know we can cover these circles by charts locally. [image]

Comment: $y=\sqrt{R^2-x^2}$ is Lipschitz away from $x=R$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The annulus, i.e.,
$$
A_{r,R}=\{(x,y):r^2<x^2+y^2<R^2\}
$$ 
where $0<r<R$ is a Lipschitz domain, since its boundary is the level set of a Lipschitz continuous function.

However, for $R>r=0$, the punctured disc
$$
A=\{(x,y):0<x^2+y^2<R^2\}
$$
is not a Lipschitz domain.

Comment: Thanks, got it!