# The boundary of a simply connected domain in the extended complex plane is connected

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

Many textbooks on complex analysis contain an equivalence result on various characterizations of simply connected domains in $\mathbb{C}$. For example, Donald Marshall's book complex analysis (p.261) states (I only picked the following 3 among a couple of characterizations there)

**Proposition:**

Suppose $\Omega$ is a domain in $\mathbb{C}$, then the following are equivalent

(1)  $\Omega$ is simple connected in the sense that any two curves with given fixed endpoints in $\Omega$ are homotopic in $\Omega$.

(2)  The complement of $\Omega$ in the extended complex plane $\mathbb{C}\cup \{\infty\}$ is connected.

(3)  The boundary of $\Omega$ in the extended complex plane is connected.

From Chapter 5 of the book and Riemann mapping theorem, I can follow the equivalence of (1) and (2). But I have no idea how to prove (1) and (3) are equivalent (this point might not be discussed in the book). Thanks for any hints or answers.

**Updated on 12/27/2023:** Assume we have proved (1) are (2) are equivalent, then there is a short proof of $(2) \Rightarrow (3)$ in the book Narasimhan-Nievergelt "Complex analysis in one variable" (p.147). The idea is show to use the properness of the Riemann map to express the boundary as a decreasing union of compact subsets in $\mathbb{C} \cup \{\infty\}$.

Namely we consider $\Omega \neq \mathbb{C}$, we have a holomorphic bijection from $f: \mathbb{D} \rightarrow \Omega$. Let $K_n$ be the closure of $f(A_n)$ in $\mathbb{C} \cup \{\infty\}$ where $A_n=\{1-\frac{1}{n}<|z|<1\}$. Let $L=\cap_{n=1}^{\infty}K_n$ the decreasing union of compact subsets in $\mathbb{C} \cup \{\infty\}$.

Then we use $f$ is proper to show $L=\partial_{\infty}\Omega$.

Note that each $K_n$, being the closure of a connected subset $f(A_n)$, is also connected. There are some further topological arguments to show $L=\cap_{n=1}^{\infty}K_n$ is also connected. We refer to Narasimhan-Nievergelt for details. Burckel's book "Classical analysis in the complex plane" (p.671) has a similar (maybe longer) argument.

For $(3) \Rightarrow (2)$. it is straightforward if we have the following lemma

**Lemma** (Theorem 1.30(v) on p.35 in Burckel)
Let $X$ be a non-empty, proper subset of $\mathbb{C}$. Then the boundary of $X$ contains the boundary of each component of $X$ and that of each component of $\mathbb{C} \setminus X$.

I have not checked the purely topological argument of $(2) \Rightarrow (3)$ by Czarnecki-Kulczycki-Lubawski (which also works in high dim, stated on $\mathbb{R}^n$) in the comment.

Comment: Author of question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4772956/connectedness-of-the-boundary-of-a-domain found short proof of equivalence here: https://eudml.org/doc/280156. Re. equivalence (1) and (2). Note that Riemann mapping does not extend to homeomorphism on the boundary of domain.

Comment: @dsh    Many thanks for the reference! For n=2, I found that Burckel's book
"Classical analysis in the complex plane" (which is mentioned in the reference) indeed have these matters, it is Exercise 10.5 on p.671 on Burckel.  At least I could try to begin the proof now (totally dumb before reading this reference). I will write again if anything interesting can be said.

Comment: @dsh  The equivalence of (1) and (2) is more standard and covered in many textbooks. Riemann mapping theorem is needed from (2) to (1).  We may try to show (2) implies Cauchy theorem holds by Runge's theorem. then the domain will satisfy the holomorphic square root property, which by the proof of Riemann mapping, gives the domain is homeo to a disk, hence simply-connected.