# Property of Lipschitz Domains

Tags: geometric-topology, diffeomorphism

I have been working on a research problem of mine and came across the concept of Lipschitz domains. I am curious about whether it is possible to show that there always exists a bi-Lipschitz map from $\mathcal{X} \to \mathcal{Y}$ whenever $\mathcal{X}, \mathcal{Y} \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ are Lipschitz domains.

I came across a result which shows the converse, i.e, if there exists a bi-Lipschitz map between $\mathcal{X}$ and $\mathcal{Y}$ and $\mathcal{X}$ is a Lipschitz domain then $\mathcal{Y}$ is also a Lipschitz domain. From my understanding of the topic (which is relatively limited), I think that there should exist a map between Lipschitz domains. However, I haven't been able to prove this claim or find a reference that proves/disproves the claim.

Any leads/references will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What is your definition of a Lipschitz domain? More specifically, what topological properties do you require for such domains? In your question, do you assume that the closures of ${\mathcal X}, {\mathcal Y}$ are homeomorphic?

Comment: I am using the definition on the wikipedia page or the one in this post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1125928/understanding-lipschitz-domain. If assuming that the closures of $\mathcal{X}$ and $\mathcal{Y}$ being homeomorphic helps (and is necessary), please feel free to assume that. In general, if there are additional conditions required to show the claim, I'd be interested in knowing about them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the definition you quoted, the existence of a bilipschitz homeomorphism is utterly wrong. The simplest example is $X={\mathbb R}$ and $Y=(0,1)\subset \mathbb R$. One can give more interesting examples when both domains are bounded, for instance, $X$ is the unit disk in $\mathbb R^2$ and $Y$ is an annulus in $\mathbb R^2$ bounded by two disjoint circles. In the latter case, $X, Y$ are not even homeomorphic.

On the other hand, if you assume that both $X, Y$ are relatively compact Lipschitz domains in $R^n$ and there exists a homeomorphism $\bar{X}\to \bar Y$, then there exists also a bilipschitz homeomorphism $\bar X\to \bar Y$, unless $n=5, n=4$, see

*Tukia, P.; Väisälä, J.*, [**Lipschitz und quasiconformal approximation and extension**](https://doi.org/10.5186/aasfm.1981.0626), Ann. Acad. Sci. Fenn., Ser. A I, Math. 6, 303-342 (1981). [ZBL0448.30021](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0448.30021).

as well as

*Luukkainen, Jouni*, [**Lipschitz and quasiconformal approximation of homeomorphism pairs**](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0166-8641(99)00145-5), Topology Appl. 109, No. 1, 1-40 (2001). [ZBL0964.57023](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0964.57023).

Comment: Ofc, compactness will also be needed. Sorry, I forgot to mention that. Thanks a lot for the references! That does answer my question. The manuscripts are too technical for me but if what you wrote is the gist, then that is close to what I was looking for. Thanks!